# Highcharts ( stockchart series line is not connecting to the last point

Tags: highcharts

I'm currently looking to implement Highcharts JS into my application.i'm using timestamp for plotting graph data

However, I have gaps in my graph but in data there is no null values, and i wish to connect the gaps.

Using the highcharts demo, I have edited the data to demonstrate what currently happens by default:

Please check this
[jsfiddle][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/r9TzZ/21/`check fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this

it's simply working fine by remove the `gapSize: 5` on my code

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9TzZ/22/)